# How to send FCM token to view?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I need to send the FCM token together with the device uuid and user id to my server.
I am able to send a request to the server directly but on this step, when I get the token (didReceiveRegistrationToken) I have no information about the user yet. I also don't have any user credentials within the app, which is using a WebView.

My first approach was to call a method within the ViewController which is communicating with the frontend view over `evaluateJavaScript` but this doesn't work as the webView is not yet there. So my question is, can I store the token somewhere within the app and use it after the webView is ready?

For me it's a little bit wierd, because when I put some prints within the steps I see the ViewController before the didReceiveRegistrationToken delegate receive the token. But when I try to call the webView from there I get an error about webView is nil. It's strange.

By the way, to pass the token directly to the server is not an option because the application doesn't know anything about the user.

Comment: You should save it in UserDefaults and then send it to server when you have user info available.

Comment: Thanks, I use the UserDefaults and observe a key. Also I send a message from JS to Swift ones the user data is loded from cache or when user just logged in. This message triggers the sending of the token to JS.